# How do you subclass UIView and add another UIView inside of it with the same frame

Tags: swift, uiview, frame, subclassing, redraw

Hi I am trying to create a custom loading bar view by subclassing `UIView`. I want to create one `UIView` with a fixed frame, and another `UIView` that is inside of it. When I initialize the inner `UIView`, with the frame passed in by this method `override init(frame: CGRect)`, the two views have different origins. I want the two views to be directly on top of each other to start out. I also want to be able to update the `innerBar` by calling this `uploadBar.setLoadingPercentage(percent: 53.5)`

Here is the code:

**Creating the `UploadBar`**

```
let uploadBar = UploadBar(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 400, height: 40))
view.addSubview(uploadBar)
```

**Subclassing `UploadBar`**

```
import UIKit

class UploadBar: UIView {

    var innerBar: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        innerBar = UIView(frame: frame)
        innerBar.backgroundColor = UI.customBlue()
        addSubview(innerBar)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setLoadingPercentage(percent: Double) {
        // change innerBar's frame and redraw
    }




}
```

[image: The White bar is the view that I am subclassing the blue bar is <code>innerBar</code>]

Answer (score 2):

For your inner view, you only require the `width` and `height` from the parent rect. The `x` and `y` should be zero relative to the parent view:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    let innerRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)

    innerBar = UIView(frame: innerRect)
    innerBar.backgroundColor = UI.customBlue()
    addSubview(innerBar)
}
```